# Ruby on Rails: Retrieve value for every hour in last 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sensor that sends in a value say ever 5 mins. This is being stored in a table along with the time stamp. I am using the code below to retrieve all values of that sensor in last 24 hours.

```
series = sensor.raindata.all(:order => "time_stamp", :conditions =>  {:time_stamp => Date.today...Date.today+1} )
```

But as the sensor us updating every 5 mins this is huge data. How do I sample the just one data point every hour? That is I need one value of that sensor per every hour. (I don't need the average for every hour. Just one sample per hour)

What is the most elegant way of achieving this? Is it possible to modify the above query to fetch this kind of data? or only way to do it is by post processing 'series' array?

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is probably with SQL. Here's an example, though I had to make a lot of assumptions about your setup to give it. 
I'm assuming:

- you're using Rails 3, and thus can use this syntax
- you have a model named Sensor, of which each
  object is a reading from the sensor that has fields named time_stamp
  and reading
- an average of the readings in an hour is an acceptable
  value for that hour
- that your database is some flavor of SQL (the example works in PostgreSQL, minor modifications may be needed for others)

So, with those disclaimers out of the way, here's the example:

```
Sensor.select('avg(reading) as avg_reading, extract(hour from time_stamp) as hour').where(:time_stamp => Date.today...Date.today+1).group('extract(hour from time_stamp)').order('hour')
```

This will give you a collection of Sensor objects (sort of), each of which responds to `.hour` and `.avg_reading`.

Alternatively (if, for instance, you're not on Rails 3), you should be attempting to execute a SQL query that looks something like this (inserting dates where indicated):

```
SELECT AVG(reading) AS avg_reading, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_stamp) AS hour FROM sensors WHERE time_stamp > {start date} AND time_stamp < {end date} GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_stamp) ORDER BY hour
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: An alternative would be a sub-select that chooses the `min(id)` after grouping by hour; for PostgreSQL: `select model.* from model where id in (select min(id) from model group by date_trunc('hour', time_stamp)) order by time_stamp`. You'd have to something instead of `date_trunc` for some other databases though.